# How to substitute n characters in each line of a file by position

Tags: position, character, line, aix, substitution

I have to anonymize fields in a file which have no delimiters.

In my case, by chance, those fieds are the one after the other.

exemple :

1234LASTNAME1¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤FIRSTNAME1¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤2013-01-01
2345LASTNAME2¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤FIRSTNAME2¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤2013-01-02
3456LASTNAME3¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤FIRSTNAME3¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤2013-02-01
4567LASTNAME1¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤FIRSTNAME2¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤2013-01-01

So, I have to substitute characters 5 to 44 by the character 'X' in order to have in result :
1234XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX2013-01-01
2345XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX2013-01-02
3456XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX2013-02-01
4567XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX2013-01-01

With awk, sed, perl ... anything working AIX version 6.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant but:

```
sed -e 's/^\(....\)........................................\(..........\)/\1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\2/' file
```

where "file" is the path to your input file.